# status 200 but I dont get some of the response. python requests

Tags: python, rest, python-requests

I am using python-request to get some  data .
I get  the response with 200 status  but is not complete, I think its due to  the strange characters of the response because  it works correctly in postman.

This is my call:

```
headers = {
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
    'Accept-Language': 'en',
    'x-access-token': token,
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36',
    'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-origin',
    'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'cors',
    'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'empty',
  
}
r= requests.get(url ,headers=headers,  cert=(ca_cert,ca_key))
```

This is the response in python

```
b'{"entities":[],"pagination":{"limit":1000,"offset":0,"count":0},"sort":{"orderDirection":"ASC","orderFieldName":"name"}}'
```

This is the response in postman:

```
{"entities":[{"id":"ff80808172c6601d0172ddc6a4f04947","name":{"ar":"2019 الانتخابات الفرعية للبلاكتاون ، كوتاموندرا وموراي","tw":"2019年布莱克敦，库塔曼德拉和默里的州补选","vi":"Cuộc bầu cử quốc gia năm 2019","el":"2019 Δημόσιες βουλευτικές εκλογές για τους","en":"NSW State General Election 2019","it":"Elezioni suppletive dello stato del 2019","cn":"2019年布萊克敦，庫塔曼德拉和默里的州補選"},"alias":"SG1901","welcomeText":{"ar":"الرسالة الافتراضية","tw":"默認消息","vi":"Thông báo mặc định","el":"Προεπιλεγμένο μήνυμα","en":"Default Message","it":"Messaggio predefinito","cn":"默认消息"},"startDate":1552251600000,"endDate":1616482800000,"boardConfiguration":"SECURITY_CERTIFICATES_PREDEFINED_CERTS","securityModel":"VERIFIABLE_MIXING","electoralBoardCreated":true,"adminBoardCreated":true,"bothBoardsCreated":false,"locales":["en","it","el","ar","tw","cn","vi"],"numElections":1}],"pagination":{"limit":1000,"offset":0,"count":1},"sort":{"orderDirection":"ASC","orderFieldName":"name"}}
```

How can I get the full response in python?

Comment: what are your headers and are they identical between the two programs? the response appears completely different, not just altered

Comment: the answers are the same except for the first element  of 'entities' which is a list of elements. In postman this list is full but in python is empty: [].
The headers are exactly the same

Comment: status 200 often means only that server recognized url in request, not that you send correct data in request.

Comment: if there are different results then it has to be something different in request. ie. different token, `GET` instead of `POST`, etc.

Comment: as I know In `postman` is function (probably in content menu - right mouse click) to generate code in `Python` (or at least to generate command for `curl` and later you can convert `curl` to `Python` on page https://curl.trillworks.com/) - **EDIT:** see `postman` doc [Generate code snippets](https://learning.postman.com/docs/postman/sending-api-requests/generate-code-snippets/)

Comment: this is how I am getting the python call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was trying to get the information very fast.( this information is generated in server after y upload a csv file).
So I resolved with a sleep at the end.
Thanks anyway for your attention.